# Changing local variable using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, local-variables

I am using a recursive function implemented in a python class. Am I right that the local variable (passed through the methods attributes) isn't changing through a recursive change?

I have the following tree:
[example tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWLfC.png)

My current method is the following:

```
def readSequence(self, linkTable, partTable, seq, element):
    #clearFlags returns an array of objects with flags set to 0
    partTable = self.clearFlags(partTable)
    #readFlags returns an array of objects with updated flags. (flag > 0 if object is in sequence)
    partTable = self.readFlags(partTable, seq)
    #readChildren returns an array of objects with all children of the current element
    children = self.readChildren(linkTable, partTable, element)

    if len(children) == 0:
        self.subsequences.append(seq)
    else:
        for child in children:
            if child.flag == 1:
                self.subsequences.append(seq)
                return
            else:
                seq.append(child)
                self.readSequence(linkTable, partTable, seq, child)
```

In my understanding the sequence *seq* should grow as follows:

1. `[1]`
2. `[1, 2]`
3. `[1, 2, 4]` --> appended to subsequences
4. `[1, 2, 5]` --> appended to subsequences
5. `[1, 3]` --> appended to subsequences

But instead it does this:

1. `[1]`
2. `[1, 2]`
3. `[1, 2, 4]` --> appended to subsequences
4. `[1, 2, 4, 5]` --> appended to subsequences
5. `[1, 2, 4, 5, 3]` --> appended to subsequences

The problem is clearly that the sequence *seq* is changed like a global variable and doesn't stay the same to add the other child.

Hope you can help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `list` is a **mutable** type in python, and that means that if you do `seq = [1,2,3]; b = seq; b.append(4)` then `seq` is now `[1,2,3,4]`. Likewise if you pass `seq` to a function, and the function modifies it, then `seq` is really modified, not just a copy. If you don't want this behaviour, use a non-mutable type, such as a `tuple` instead of a `list`; or explicitly make a copy, using `list(seq)` or `seq.copy()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` is a **mutable** type in python.

Essentially, that means that lists are passed by reference rather than by value; if two variables refer to the same list, then modifying one will reflect on the other.

For instance:

```py
seq = [1,2,3]
b = seq
b.append(4)
print(seq) # [1,2,3,4]
```

Likewise if you pass `seq` to a function, and the function modifies it, then `seq` is really modified, not just a copy:

```py
def f(l):
    l.append(4)

seq = [1,2,3]
f(l)
print(seq) # [1,2,3,4]
```

If you don't want this behaviour, then there are three possible solutions:

- Use a non-mutable type, such as a `tuple`, instead of a `list`; or
- explicitly make a copy, using `list(seq)` or `seq.copy()`; or
- undo the changes before you return from the recursive call.

### Use a non-mutable type or explicitly make a copy

For instance:

```py
# USING A NON-MUTABLE TYPE

def f(l):
    l = (*l, 4)

seq = (1,2,3) # tuple
f(seq)
print(seq) # (1,2,3)
```

```py
# MAKING A COPY

def f(l):
    l.append(4)

seq = [1,2,3]
f(list(seq)) # explicitly pass a copy rather than the original
print(seq) # [1,2,3]
```

### Undo the changes before returning from the recursive call

The two options above would add to the complexity of your function, because making a copy at every recursive call takes time linear in the length of the list at every recursive call.

Instead, you can undo your `list.append` by following it with a `list.pop`.

Replace:

```py
                seq.append(child)
                self.readSequence(linkTable, partTable, seq, child)
```

with:

```py
                seq.append(child)
                self.readSequence(linkTable, partTable, seq, child)
                seq.pop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I was searching for.